# Golang and JSON with array of struct

Tags: json, go, struct

I would like to create a JSON of a `GatewayInfo` where the type are defined like this:

```
type SpanInfo struct {
    imsi string
    network string
    network_status string
    signal_quality int
    slot int
    state string
}

type GatewayInfo []SpanInfo
```

The gateway information is created with:

```
var gatewayInfo = make(GatewayInfo, nb_spans)
```

To create the JSON, I use the `json.Marshal` function:

```
gatewayInfo := getGatewayInfo(spans)
log.Printf("Polling content: %s\n", gatewayInfo)

jsonInfo, _ := json.Marshal(gatewayInfo)
log.Printf("jsonInfo: %s\n", jsonInfo)
```

Unfortunately the result is not what I was expecting:

```
2015/02/09 13:48:26 Polling content: [{652020105829193 20801 Registered (Roaming) %!s(int=17) %!s(int=2) } {652020105829194 20801 Registered (Roaming) %!s(int=16) %!s(int=3) } {652020105829192 20801 Registered (Roaming) %!s(int=19) %!s(int=1) } {652020105829197 20801 Registered (Roaming) %!s(int=19) %!s(int=4) }]
2015/02/09 13:48:26 jsonInfo: [{},{},{},{}]
```

As we can see, the `GatewayInfo` instance has the `SpanInfo`, but in the JSON I have empty `SpanInfo`.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Your struct fields must be exported (field is exported if it begins with a capital letter) or they won't be encoded:

> Struct values encode as JSON objects. Each exported struct field
>   becomes a member of the object

To get the JSON representation as probably expected change the code to this:

```
type SpanInfo struct {
    IMSI string `json:"imsi"`
    Network string `json:"network"`
    NetworkStatus string `json:"network_status"`
    SignalQuality int `json:"signal_quality"`
    Slot int `json:slot"`
    State string `json:"state"`
}

type GatewayInfo []SpanInfo
```

Comment: While code this answer works, Arjan should probably note that the fields' names should start in upper case. (see icza answer below),

Comment: @VěrošK.Added clarification

Comment: it took me an hour to found this solution. Thanks

Answer (score 13):

The [`json`](http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/) package can only serialize exported fields of your struct. Change your struct to start all fields with an uppercase letter so they can be included in the output:

```
type SpanInfo struct {
    Imsi string
    Network string
    Network_status string
    Signal_quality int
    Slot int
    State string
}
```

Read the documentation of [`json.Marshal()`](http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Marshal) for details and more information.

Comment: This works for me, tested on  go 1.21

Answer (score 0):

---

> This is not a new answer. It is just consolidation of comments on the
>   accepted answer.

---

**From ORIGINAL Query**

```
type SpanInfo struct {
    imsi string
    network string
    network_status string
    signal_quality int
    slot int
    state string
}
```

**From Answer and comments - Please note that the first char of each field in struct is now in UPPER case along with json representation added to each field**

```
type SpanInfo struct {
    IMSI string `json:"imsi"`
    Network string `json:"network"`
    NetworkStatus string `json:"network_status"`
    SignalQuality int `json:"signal_quality"`
    Slot int `json:slot"`
    State string `json:"state"`
}
```